# Showing that a Normed Linear Space is incomplete and major conceptual doubt

Tags: functional-analysis

I have been asked to show that $(c_{00}, \|.\|_p)$ is an incomplete normed linear space.
Will the following sequence work?

$x^{(1)}=(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\dots\dots)$

$x^{(2)}=(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,\dots\dots)$

$x^{(3)}=(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,\dots\dots)$

$x^{(4)}=(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,\dots\dots)$

and so on.
This will converge to $x=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\dots\dots)$ which doesn't belong to $c_{00}$.

My major issue is is it necessary that the limit in the counterexample of showing incompleteness $\big((1,1,1,1,1,1,\dots) \text{ here } \big)$ must be evaluatable under the given norm? If so. why??

Comment: Your sequence $(x^{(k)})_k$ is unbounded wrt $\|\cdot\|_p$.

Comment: oh, it doesn't converge, Yes, limit is wrong

Comment: Take any element $x$ of $L^p$ whose components are non zero infinitely often. Then let the sequence be $x^n=(x_1,....,x_n,0,0,...)$.